# Neo4j: can I get statistic via JMX about traversing my graph?

Tags: neo4j, jmx

Can I get statistic via JMX about traversing my graph? I means number of nodes that has traversed in each search.

UPD. How I get statistic from my plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doesn't think you can get that information thrugh Neo4j MBeans. You can find all the supported [MBean's and their properties here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/jmx-mxbeans.html#jmx-primitive-count).

I believe what you are looking for is a [Cypher Profiler](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-cypher.html#rest-api-profile-a-query).

Comment: Thanks. But I didn't use Cypher. I use plugin.